# Ad-hoc support in Cyanogenmod 10.x?

Tags: wi-fi, 4.2-jelly-bean

I flashed Cyanogen 10.1.3 to my Samsung GT-P3113 (the P3110 version which is compatible) in the hopes of getting IBSS ad-hoc support that was added in CM-10.1 alpha2. (see the release note item for it here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2214042)

However I can't see my ad-hoc network in the wifi list. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: That thread is a changelog for a different device. I don't know that CM has ad-hoc networking on every device they support, so the changelog there is probably not indicative of general CM features/changes. Commits to their review system imply that IBSS support is dependent on the WiFi driver, which will vary by device/kernel: http://review.cyanogenmod.org/#/c/33728/

Comment: Alright! Thanks for the help. You should have answered, I would have given to the credit. (you still can ;)

Comment: So just a dumb Q, but I assumed that Cyanogen included their own kernel and device drivers. I mean the kernel had to come from somewhere first off. Are they basing their device builds on the manufacturer provided rom/source/kernel? And how can you confirm if your device doesn't support something like this? (said it was a dumb Q)

Comment: I'm not really sure of an easy way to check (for that reason, I can't say for certain that your device does/doesn't support IBSS ). CM does have their own kernel repos, and they are generally based on the kernels released by the manufacturers. Different devices typically have different kernel code, though some similar ones may share (e.g. the [espresso kernel](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_kernel_samsung_espresso10) is used by several variants of the Galaxy Tab). Consequently, features that require kernel driver modifications may not necessarily be available to all devices.